# wxwidgets UI update: declaring window identifier

Tags: c++, events, user-interface, wxwidgets

**WXWIDGET UI UPDATE/DYNAMIC EVENT HANDLING PROBLEM**

Currently using: `wxwidgets 2.8.12` with `GCC 4.6.2 [mingw]`

I am having problems in doing UI update for a `wxListCtrl`.

After defining the `wxListCtrl` in the *constructor* of my `wxFrame` class as

```
wxListCtrl* listbox = new wxListCtrl(this, ID_LIST, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400,400), wxLC_REPORT|wxLC_SINGLE_SEL|wxLC_HRULES|wxLC_VRULES);
```

I need to update/insert values of `wxListCtrl` in a different `wxFrame` member function.

I do this by:

```
void MyFrame::test()
{
    wxListCtrl* listbox = (wxListCtrl*) FindWindow(ID_LIST);
    listbox -> InsertItem(0, "1");  
    listbox -> SetItem(0, 1, "test");
}
```

After doing this I realized that  `ID_LIST` needs to be declared which I am not sure how that is done.

Also as a reference I did look up the `wxwidget book` and they do try to give an example but I was not able to understand.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about `enum { ID_LIST };`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg **SOLVED**, `Thanks` that works. I did think of `enum` but in the wxwidget it mentioned something about linking the declaration with custom event handling functions which added to the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking FindWindow every time you want to do something with a widget, it is usual to store the pointer to the widget in your class.

```
// in class definition
wxListCtrl * mylistbox 

// in constructor
mylistbox = new wxListCtrl(this, ID_LIST, ...

// in test method    
mylistbox -> InsertItem(0, "1");
```